# after OAuth redirect fragment gets lost

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, shiro

I have a web environment where I'm accessing my resources using fragments. (like foo.com/#/my_resource).

I'm trying to add authentication using OAuth 2 to my server. And I'm using Shiro framework with pac4j. The problem I have here is, after I log in to the provider, the browser loses my hash so I get redirected to foo.com/ instead of foo.com/#/my_resource.

Thought it might be a common problem. Are there any workarounds for this? Is this behavior expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a request to a URL with a fragment, the fragment is not sent to the server - it is a client-side only concept. So the server would be unable to redirect to a URL and include the original fragment.

Also, it's not quite clear from your question, but if what you mean is that you are using this as the `redirect_uri` parameter in an OAuth 2 request, the spec [explicitly forbids the use of a fragment in the value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2).

Comment: I'm not sending the fragment within redirect_uri parameter, and I'm handling the OAuth on server side. So the redirects don't really know about hash at all as you said. But the browser keeps the hash during redirects as far as I know. At least the fragment is still there in the browser when I get redirected to the login page of the OAuth provider. But after logging in, I get redirected to my domain back again, yet fragment is lost.

Comment: A redirect tells the browser to change to a completely different location, sent by the server. Why would you expect it to retain the fragment when the server has no knowledge of what it was? If you debug the requests and responses your browser (e.g. with firebug or chrome) it should be obvious what's happening.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong OAuth workflow. Fragments are used within the "implicit grant" scenario with javascript clients. Fragment is completely a client-side concept anyway.